# Selecting rows with unique column values

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to write an SQL command that returns `emails` that has the value 
 (***track openers***) and doesn't have the value (***redirect***) for the column `action_type` in the same table.

```
email              countrycode    action_type
email1@domain.com  GB             track openers
email1@domain.com  GB             redirect
email2@domain.com  GB             track openers
email2@domain.com  GB             redirect
email3@domain.com  GB             track openers
email3@domain.com  GB             redirect
email4@domain.com  GB             track openers <<
```

[DB Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7wMh.png)
[image]

I have already tried this without success, it continues to show loading... without returning any results

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(email) as `email`, `action_type`, `countrycode`
FROM `stats`
WHERE `email` NOT IN (SELECT `email` FROM `stats` WHERE `action_type` = 'redirect');
```

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function. It's a part of SELECT DISTINCT and works on the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(email) as ...` to make code clearer!

Comment: Thank you for this info @jarlh, i will edit my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest aggregation:

```
SELECT LOWER(email) as email
FROM `stats`
WHERE action_type in ('redirect', 'track openers')
GROUP BY LOWER(email)
HAVING MIN(action_type) = MAX(action_type) AND
       MIN(action_type) = 'track openers';
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be an option. Here you look for all emails, that has action type `track openers` and for which doesn't exists an action with `redirect` action type.

```
SELECT LOWER(email)
FROM stats s
WHERE s.action_type = 'track openers' AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT ss.email
    FROM stats ss
    WHERE s.email = ss.email
    AND ss.action_type = 'redirect'
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it continues to show loading... without returning any results

Comment: Maybe the reason is that you are using mysql, while i had tested it with postgres. That was my inattention. Anyway, you are welcome !

Answer (score 0):

A slightly less verbose option

```
SELECT LOWER(email) as email
FROM `stats`
WHERE action_type in ('redirect', 'track openers') --optional if there are only 2 types
GROUP BY email
HAVING AVG(CASE WHEN action_type ='track openers' THEN 1 END) = 1;
```